# How to make clean to my stack?

Tags: rosmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a stack with a lot of packages.

When I copy the whole directory to another ubuntu machine, I have to rebuild all packages.

But if I don't make clean package one by one, it will get stuck when the package with dependency that haven't make clean.

How do I make clean to all my packages in one stack?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12322/how-to-make-clean-to-my-stack?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2011-12-13

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
rosmake --target=clean
```

For any directory this should work:

```
for i in $(find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d); do cd $i; make clean; cd -; done
```

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-12-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) on 2011-12-13**:
rosmake --target=clean *  :: from that directory will work fine as it will ignore dirs that are neither package nor stack and other files in there. But remember rosmake will try to clean all deps which might be a pain if ros is installed in userspace. Therefore thanks for the loop make script!

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-12-13**:
It isn't a stack then.

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2011-12-13**:
If I didn't use roscreate-stack but using only a directory to contain all packages, what's the simplest way to clean all packages?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

##To rosmake clean  all packages, use :

#`rosmake -a --target=clean`

---

Originally posted by [routeaccess](https://answers.ros.org/users/13316/routeaccess/) with karma: 11 on 2014-06-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1